# StarSchema modeling

Tags: sql, ssas

Today I came across a modeling that I did not understand.

I opened a data warehouse project with the following tables:

Dimensions:
- Dim_Store
- Dim_Date
- Dim_Customer
- Dim_Location

Fact:
- FactSales

The fact FactSales is getting the relationship of the dimensions (Star Schema), so far ok.

But in SSAS there were four more tables that are not related to Fact.

Is this correct?
As far as I know all dimensions need to be relating to Fact or not?

_Thanks

Comment: Hi, when you say "the four dimensions are not joined", where are you looking ? The .DSV or the .cube ? No link in the DSV does not mean there is no link between a dimension and a measure group.

Comment: Hi, In table modeling in SQL Server.
When I go to "Database Diagrams" in SQL Server all tables are related to the fact except those 4 tables. Can this scenario occur? or am i required to relate all dimensions to fact?.... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a star schema, the facts table should be joined with all the denormalized dimension tables but if some dimensions are joined to each other then it is a snowflake schema.

Comment: Ok I got it.
But in my case, the four dimensions are not joined with the fact table or dimensions.

I didn't understand why they modeled it this way.

Thanks for the feedback.